# Docker Swarm failover

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, docker-swarm, azure-virtual-machine, failover

In a simple Docker Swarm setup, one master (on Linux) and two workers (one on Linux and the other on Windows) are configured. All three nodes are physical machines; and, the master is also running as a worker.
Our observation is that, despite two workers, the master runs every docker container (around 10 containers having cron schedule in each container) in itself.
The questions are,

1) For failover setup, how many masters or workers or both should be added in the swarm ?

2) In case of new nodes, is it feasible to integrate Azure VMs as new nodes to our current swarm ?

3) How to setup failover to cover scenarios like,

a) A container running on a host is fine, but the cron jobs inside the container is failing ?

b) The network outage on one node results in container-deployment on another node; but, the first node returns again on network ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. The best practice is implement an odd number of manager nodes. 1, 3, 5..
2. I'm not sure if there is a final solution but Round robin dns could be the solution o manually point to any IP address of the swarm. Thanks to the Routing Mesh Docker swarm can redirect the request to the correct node.
3. Yes, if the connection is lost then docker redistribute the tasks but if the node come back Docker dont' assign it tasks again automatically. It hast to occur an update to redistribute the tasks.